# iOS Quickblox APNS across apps

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox

We want to make the Quickblox chat (and chat's APNS) work in two (separate) iPhone apps **using a single Quickblox application**?

So we will be using a single Quickblox appplication in both iPhone apps.. i.e. same QBSettings in both the iPhone apps. (same set of ApplicationID, AuthKey, AuthSecret and AccountKey in both apps, so that Quickblox can send/receive messages from both apps, as it should consider those as same..)

Can it work as such? and can we upload the two set of certificates for each app for sending APNS to respective app users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use same qbsettings on both the devices.
Just signup and login with two users and you are good to go.

You can work with the one APNS for both users too.
Below link will help to to start with a simple chat project

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

To setup push notifications:

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios

Comment: Hi Manoj, 
Thanks a lot for answering my query.
Yes I am trying to use same QBSettings on both of my iPhone apps.
Now since these are 2 separate iPhone apps (with two different AppIDs).
So there will be two development APNS certificates (.p12) for both the app-ids. But when I upload the first app's development .p12 certificate to Quickblox admin panel, and try to upload the development .p12 certificate of the other one, it replaces the certificate of previous one. SO LOOKS LIKE IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO ADD CERTIFICATES FOR MULTIPLE APP-IDS?

Comment: Yes it looks like that is not possible. But that would be a cool feature to have.